# LDAP Authentication in Node.js with Space in OU

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js

I'm trying and failing to connect to an LDAP system with a space in the `OU` using the [`passport-ldapauth`](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth) strategy for [`passport`](http://passportjs.org/).

This fails:

```
let OPTS = {
    server: {
        url: 'ldap://ldap.company.com:PORT',
        bindDn: 'CN=some-group,OU=Utils,OU=Some Users,DC=thing,DC=com',
        bindCredentials: 'my$pass',
        searchBase: 'ou=some users,DC=thing,DC=com',
        searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})'
    }
};
```

But this succeeds on the command line:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.company.com:PORT -x -D 'CN=some-group,OU=Utils,OU=Some Users,DC=thing,DC=com' -w 'my$pass' -b 'ou=some users,DC=thing,DC=com' "(uid=username)"
```

I've tried every combination of escaped quotes, spaces, and combined `'` and `"` that I can think of to no avail. The response is always `Unauthorized` in the application even though the same credentials succeed in the command line.

Comment: LDAP would not require ",OU=Some Users," to be escaped. Must be something within the node.js implementation.

Comment: You're right. This turned out to be an issue with the credentials on the LDAP side. The simple `401 Unauthorized` response made it very difficult to track this down so I'm looking into PRing a more detailed message into the tool. Thanks for taking a look!